# array.insert at: replaces item instead of inserting at the specified location in Swift, why?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have the following `imagePickerController` delegate function, every time I select an image it replaces the previous `urlString` of the uploaded image to `Firebase Storage`, instead of **inserting** at the second to last array.count - 1 position (by design as I use the last entry to dequeue a different `cell` in the `collectionview`) of the `images` array. Resulting in the last image urlString always being replaced by the latest one.

**I must add**, if I upload one image at a time by navigating away from the current VC then returning and uploading another image again then it works as expected.

The result of the print statements in the code are as follows:

Upload image 1:

```
0. ADDING images.count: 3
1. ADDING images.count: 4
2. ADDING images.count: 4
images.last item: Optional("dummy string")
```

Upload image 2 (**image count has not increased**):

```
0. ADDING images.count: 4
1. ADDING images.count: 4
2. ADDING images.count: 4 
images.last item: Optional("dummy string")
```

Function:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        Utilities.run.showSVHUD(uiView: self.view, status: "Saving")

        var selectedImageFromPicker: UIImage?

        if let editedImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"] as? UIImage {
            selectedImageFromPicker = editedImage
        } else if let originalImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage {

            selectedImageFromPicker = originalImage
        }

        if let selectedImage = selectedImageFromPicker {

            guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

            print("0. ADDING images.count: \(self.images.count)")

            DataService.run.uploadProfileImageToFirebaseStorage(image: selectedImage) { (success, urlString) in

                self.images.insert(urlString, at: self.images.count - 1)
                print("1. ADDING images.count: \(self.images.count)")
                let slice = self.images.dropLast()
                let urlArray = Array(slice) //Converting Slice to Array
                let dictionary = urlArray.indexedDictionary //converting to Dictionary

                DataService.run.updateProfileImagesValueForUser(uid: uid, imagesUrls: dictionary, handler: { (success) in

                    if success {
                        Utilities.run.dismissSVHUD(delay: 0.5)
                        print("2. ADDING images.count: \(self.images.count)")
                        print("images.last item: \(String(describing: self.images.last))")
                        self.collectionView.reloadData()
                        self.collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
                    }//end if success

                })// end updateProfileImagesValueForUser

            }//end uploadProfileImageToFirebaseStorage

        }//end if let selectedImage = selectedImageFromPicker

    }//end func
```

`images` array is initiated from the `User` object passed which contains an array of `String` objects.

```
func initData(forUser user:User) {

    self.user = user

}//end func
```

`setupviews()` is called in `viewWillAppear()` which initialises `images` array

```
func setupViews(){

    images = user!.profileImages

    images.append("dummy string")

    let imageString = user!.profilePictureURL
    let url = URL(string: imageString)//create URL from string
    profileImg.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "placeholder"), options: [.continueInBackground])

}//end func
```

Comment: I see no code that does the things you mentioned in the question. The only operations on array are the slicing and an `indexedDictionary` call (what's that method doing, btw?).

Comment: yes, which is why I'm struggling to find what is the caused for the item to continually be replaced instead of inserted. Not sure if you took noticed on my question, but this doesn't occur if I navigate away from the VC return and upload image again it works as expected. Only when I stay on the same VC and attempt to upload images in series without navigating away is when I see this bug. `indexedDictionary` is an extension that simply converts the `array` to a `Dictionary` in readiness to upload to user's profile in `Firebase`.

Comment: You need to share more code as this code can not produce the issue. As `images` is an instance variable so i believe it is manipulated somewhere else.

Comment: Swift `Array` or `NSMutableArray` is not thread-safe. If it is referenced or modified from multiple threads simultaneously, the result is unpredictable, _replace instead of insert_ may happen. Do your `upload...` methods call `handler` inside the main queue? If no, enclose all critical parts with `DispatchQueue.main.async {...}`.

Comment: @OOPer thanks for your suggestion, are you able to please make the edits to my code so that I can better visualise your response?

Comment: @Roggie, usually, I do not post  unverified codes (at least, I check my code compiles without errors before posting it). You may need to fix many parts, is that ok?

Comment: @OOPer I appreciate your response...now where to start debugging this :/

Comment: @Roggie, if your issue is really caused by simultaneous multiple access as I suggested, it is very hard to debug. Running under control of debugger may change many behaviors. Just try to code with care. Enclosing all suspicious parts with `DispatchQueue.main.async {...}` is one way.

Comment: @OOPer thanks, I've tried a couple of places to enclose some key code with a `DispatchQueue.main.async {...}` to no avail. Do you think another reason why could because of an "old" memory reference when doing the `insert` twice?

Comment: I cannot say any more with the code shown above. And i do not see if you have done it correctly or not, with just reading _to no avail_. Anyway SO does not like me to continue posting comments. Hope your issue solved soon, good luck.

Comment: @OOPer FYI - The issue stemmed back to the `images` array being overwritten every time in my `viewWillAppear` function, I've sinced moved it to `viewDidLoad` which appears to have solved the problem :)

Comment: Thanks for reporting. Happy to hear that you solved your issue. (And found things what I was missing when I wrote my comments.)